# What charset should I use for storing emails in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, email, character-encoding

Do email addresses store fine in an **ascii** charset, or would I need to use **utf8**?

Comment: Use the same charset as the rest of your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 6530](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6530) allows non-ASCII characters so if you need to plan ahead better choice would be UTF-8.

BTW I never saw an e-mail address with non-ASCII characters so it's probably safe to use latin1:)

EDIT:
As [wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Valid_email_addresses), these are all valid addresses according to RFC 6530:

- Pelé@example.com (Latin Alphabet (with diacritics))
- δοκιμή@παράδειγμα.δοκιμή (Greek Alphabet)
- 甲斐@黒川.日本 (Japanese Characters)
- чебурашка@ящик-с-апельсинами.рф (Cyrillic Characters)